# Route user to users#show after devise password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When my user logs in, I would like them to default to their own "show" page as I don't want a listing of users viewable. So to do this, I have changed the default after_sign_in, like this;

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(current_user)
end
```

Works great. It goes wrong after a password change. I need to modify the root path so that after a change, it goes to the show page

```
root :to => "users#show"
```

..but now, obviously, I don't have an :id, so I get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User without an ID
```

...which makes sense. I am using the controllers which ship with devise, so my question is, how do I hook the password change and send the user to their show page? Should I be able to just edit the def show to say

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) || current_user
```

or do I need to modify my

```
root :to => "users#show"
```

to reflect the id of the current_user, assuming devise logged the user back in automatically.... or did it never log them out...?

Thanks

Comment: Just ask, what do you mean password change, on `edit their password` or `password reset after forgot password`?

Comment: If it works incorrectly after a password change, maybe you want to consider passing in the current_user again to make sure the user is properly updated

Comment: thanks both - I mean a password edit - that is, changing their password whilst logged in...oshikryu - how do you mean  - can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this;

First up, update your routes file to use the status of Devise so authenticated users are treated differently

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "users#show"
end
unauthenticated :user do
  devise_scope :user do 
    get "/" => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
end
```

Now make sure that when user#show happens, current_user is looked up and used to combat the fact that the users#show has no :id

```
def show
if params[:id].nil? # if there is no user id in params, show current one
  @user = current_user
else
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Its all good!

Thanks